# onmousemove in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, esri

How do you implement onmousemove in Firefox? I have it working in IE7 but no `alert` pops in Firefox. Is is not supported or done differently?

```
<esri:Map ID="Map1" runat="server" MapResourceManager="MapResourceManager1" 
    Height="100%" Width="100%" VirtualDirectory="" 
    PrimaryMapResource="ESRI_Imagery_World_2D" Extent="-130,37,-117,46" 
    onmousemove="alert()" >
</esri:Map>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thinkk the problem is that you need to put something inside your alert(), such as:

```
<esri:Map ID="Map1" runat="server" MapResourceManager="MapResourceManager1" 
                    Height="100%" Width="100%" VirtualDirectory="" 
                    PrimaryMapResource="ESRI_Imagery_World_2D" Extent="-130,37,-117,46" 
                    onmousemove="alert('test');" >
                </esri:Map>
```

I just tried this and it worked in FF:

```
<div onmousemove="alert('test');" style="height:100px; width:300px; background-color:#f00;"></div>
```